# How to make a drop-down menu in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook, react-proptypes

How to make a drop-down menu in which there will be several more drop-down menus that are generated from an array, and there can be several elements in them, using React and storybook

I can't figure out how to make a drop-down menu correctly, if I generate them via map, then they all open at once, since they have one state, but I don't understand how to make them different states

Now I have this code

```
export const Staff = ({ title, titleS, titleT, titleF, pos, name, text, post, date, onClick,  ...props }) => {
    const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
    const [activeS, setActiveS] = useState(false);

    const show = () => {
        setActiveS(!activeS)
    }

    return (
       <>
           <div className={['dropdown', active ? 'dropdown--active' : ''].join(' ')}>
               <div className="dropdown__header" onClick={()=> {setActive(!active)} } >
                   <h5>{title}</h5>
               </div>
               <div className="dropdown__body">
                           <>
                                       <>
                                          <div className='task' onClick={show}>
                                              <Icon icon="bi:arrow-right-short" className={['dropdownBodyActive__prev', activeS ? 'dropdownBodyActive__icon': 'dropdownBodyActive__prev'].join(' ')} />
                                              {pos.map((item) => {
                                                  return (
                                                    <>
                                                        <div className="task__content">
                                                            <h4 className="task__name" >{item.name}</h4>
                                                            <h4 className="task__meeting">
                                                            </h4>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div className='task__date'>
                                                            {item.text}
                                                            <i className='uil uil-ellipsis-h'></i>
                                                        </div></>
                                                                                                      )
                                              })}

                                          </div>

                                           {post.map((item) => {
                                               return (
                                                   <div className={['position', activeS ? 'dropdownBodyActive': 'dropdownBody'].join(' ')}>
                                                       <div className="position__content">
                                                           <ReactSVG src={VecIcon} className='position__icon'/>
                                                           <h4 className="position__name" >{item.name}</h4>
                                                           <h4 className="position__meeting">
                                                               {/*<span>New</span>*/}
                                                           </h4>
                                                           <i className='uil uil-ellipsis-h position__dot'></i>
                                                           <div className='position__date'>
                                                               {item.text}
                                                           </div>
                                                       </div>

                                                   </div>
                                               )
                                           })}

                                       </>


                           </>

               </div>
           </div>

       </>

    );
};



Staff.propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string,
    onClick: PropTypes.func,
    text:PropTypes.string,
    date: PropTypes.object,
    pos: PropTypes.arrayOf(
        PropTypes.shape({
            text: PropTypes.string,
            name: PropTypes.string,
        })
    ),
    post: PropTypes.arrayOf(
        PropTypes.shape({
            name: PropTypes.string
        })
    ),
};

Staff.defaultProps = {
    title: '',
    pos: [],
    post: []

};
```

and stories

```
const Template = (args) => <div style={{maxWidth: "1220px"}}>
    <Staff {...args}
            text='Jankov'
    >

    <Item

    />




</Staff>


    <StaffS {...args}

            >

        <Item    />
        <Item    />

    </StaffS>

    <StaffT {...args} >

        <Item    />
        <Item    />

    </StaffT>

    <StaffF {...args} >

        <Item  />
        <Item   />

    </StaffF>


</div>;

export const Normal = Template.bind({});
Normal.args = {
    title: 'HEADQUARTERS',
    titleS: 'Design',
    titleT: 'Marketing',
    titleF: 'PR/Backoffice',
    date: {
    text: "2 Branch Office",


},


    pos: [
        {
            name: 'Development',
            text: ''
        },
        {
            name: 'České Budějovice',
            text: '2 Branch Office',

        },
    ],

    post: [
        {
            name: 'Jankov',
            text: '',


        },
        {
            name: 'České Budějovice',
            text: '2 Branch Office',

        },
        {
            name: 'Jankov',
            text: '',

        }
    ]
};
```

[image] here's how it turns out for me

[image] And here's how I need

Comment: Rather than ask _"I can't figure out how to make a drop-down menu correctly"_ please may you tell us what's wrong with your current code?

Comment: My current code is not working correctly, I am generating a drop-down menu in which the first part separately generates one element, and the second part already generates this element, but whatever I do, I can't control them, and I want to find out where I have an error

Comment: _"My current code is not working correctly"_ please add more details and clarify this _by editing the question_? Also if you have an error, please add that to the question _as text_.